# Eclipse all jobs listener

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to develop a plugin that will do some work when any kind of eclipse job is scheduled.

Basically I want to be able to know when a job is in the progress dialog and monitor it.

Is there a listener that can be set up to catch the begging and end of such jobs?

Answer (score 1):

When you think about it, the `ProgressView` does just that: whenever a Job starts, it displays it in its view.
Note, as mentioned in this thread, the [`ProgressView` is tightly coupled with the eclipse Jobs API](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg35257.html) (i.e., it may not monitor any plain vanilla thread)

[image]
<sup>(From the article [**On the Job: The Eclipse Jobs API**](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html))</sup>

So may be you can start by looking at the code in [`org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressView`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/progress/ProgressView.java.htm), which needs a [`ProgressViewerContentProvider`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/progress/ProgressViewerContentProvider.java.htm), based on a [`ProgressContentProvider`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/progress/ProgressContentProvider.java.htm) (implementing a [`IProgressUpdateCollector`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/internal/progress/IProgressUpdateCollector.java.htm))

The all thing seems to be based upon the [`ProgressViewUpdater`](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/eclipse/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/Eclipse-UI/org/eclipse/ui/internal/progress/ProgressViewUpdater.java.shtml) singleton, which create one UI thread in charge of monitoring those Jobs:

```
    /**
     * Create the update job that handles the updatesInfo.
     */
    private void createUpdateJob() {
        updateJob = new WorkbenchJob(ProgressMessages.ProgressContentProvider_UpdateProgressJob) {
            /*
             * (non-Javadoc)
             * 
             * @see org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob#runInUIThread(org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor)
             */
            public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor) {

                //Abort the job if there isn't anything
                if (collectors.length == 0) {
                    return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
                }

                if (currentInfo.updateAll) {
                    synchronized (updateLock) {
                        currentInfo.reset();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < collectors.length; i++) {
                        collectors[i].refresh();
                    }

                } else {
                    //Lock while getting local copies of the caches.
                    Object[] updateItems;
                    Object[] additionItems;
                    Object[] deletionItems;
                    synchronized (updateLock) {
                        currentInfo.processForUpdate();

                        updateItems = currentInfo.refreshes.toArray();
                        additionItems = currentInfo.additions.toArray();
                        deletionItems = currentInfo.deletions.toArray();

                        currentInfo.reset();
                    }

                    for (int v = 0; v < collectors.length; v++) {
                        IProgressUpdateCollector collector = collectors[v];

                        if (updateItems.length > 0) {
                            collector.refresh(updateItems);
                        }
                        if (additionItems.length > 0) {
                            collector.add(additionItems);
                        }
                        if (deletionItems.length > 0) {
                            collector.remove(deletionItems);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return Status.OK_STATUS;
            }
        };
        updateJob.setSystem(true);
        updateJob.setPriority(Job.DECORATE);
        updateJob.setProperty(ProgressManagerUtil.INFRASTRUCTURE_PROPERTY, new Object());

    }
```

Comment: great answer, VonC. :thumbs up:

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `JobChangeListener` in the `IJobManager` for the beginning and ending of jobs.

```
IJobManager manager = Job.getJobManager();
manager.addJobChangeListener(myJobChangeListener);
```

`IJobChangeListener` receives the following events.

```
public void aboutToRun(IJobChangeEvent event);
public void awake(IJobChangeEvent event);
public void done(IJobChangeEvent event);
public void running(IJobChangeEvent event);
public void scheduled(IJobChangeEvent event);
public void sleeping(IJobChangeEvent event);
```

I haven't found a way to track the progress of a running job, however.  I'd be curious if anyone has.